# Emailing out an item in shrepoint 2010 to users that don't have access to the site

Tags: 2010, email

I am trying to figure out how to email out one item from a list by clicking on a button.  Sort of like when you create a print button and it prints out just the one item.  I don't want all of users to have to download anything.  Is there a way just to code the webpart to create a button where your outlook email pops up with a new email and the list item and details are in the body of the email?  This would be sent to people that do not have access to the sharepoint list necessarily.  I want to do this without a workflow since it's going to be done on a case by case basis.

Comment: What version of SharePoint is it? If it's 2013, is it Online or On Premise? Thank you.

Comment: It is SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this using Javascript. This involves below steps:

1. Write some JSOM code to fetch the details of the item which you want to dump onto the email body.
2. Use the below sample technique to call outlook new mail window.

> ```
> <a class="email" title="Email the item" href="#" onclick="javascript:window.location='mailto:?subject=Sample Mail&body=I thought you might find this information interesting: ' + yourItemDetails;">Email this item</a>
> ```

Comment: Do you have suggestions on where I might find an example of the JSOM code to get the details?